# Counter Controlled While Loop Using Perfect Squares

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm new to programming and my teacher doesn't really teach us things. I need to make a program that finds the first 20 perfect squares using the `pow` function. NEEDS TO BE A COUNTER CONTROLLED LOOP. I really don't know what that means but I gave it my best shot below. Please help me!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a, b;
    cout << "Enter the num:";
    scanf("% d", &a);
    b = sqrt (a);
    if ((b * b) == a)
        cout << "The given number is a perfect square";
    else
        cout << "The given number is not a perfect square";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would have been a solution to a previous task. Have you attempted the loop task yet?

Comment: You are first including a C++ Header, then you are including a C Header and then again you are including a C++ Header. I hope this code does not come from your teacher.

Comment: Have you looked at your text book to figure out what a "counter controlled" loop is?  Asked your teacher?  Another student?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then counter controlled loop means that it should be a loop that has a variable(the counter) and a condition(for the loop), and while the variable answers the condition it should loop.
In your example an integer `i` will be the counter and the loop will be a `for` loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
    {
       cout << i << "'s perfect square is " << pow(i, 2) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! My teacher basically want us to teach ourselves because "it is the best way to learn"

Comment: No problem, you welcome. If this answers your question consider accepting this answer.